# how to load an image in UIWebView

Tags: ios6, uiwebview

i tried below two methods but only white background is appearing no image is displaying.

1.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"png"];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><img src=\"file://%@\"></body></html>",path] baseURL:nil];
```

2.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourImage" ofType:@"png"];
//Creating a URL which points towards our path
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
//Creating a page request which will load our URL (Which points to our path)
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
//Telling our webView to load our above request
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

i think both are right methods but both are useless for me.
Plz help me out.

Comment: ya thanku.But i had done with second method i was doing a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Using image data (`test_image.jpeg` in the bundle is going to be loaded in the webView)

   ```
   NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test_image" ofType:@"jpeg"];
   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
   [webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"image/jpeg" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
   ```
2. Loading as HTML content

   ```
   NSURL *imageUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test_image" withExtension:@"jpeg"];
   NSString *htmString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><img border=\"0\" src=\"%@\" width=\"304\" height=\"228\"></body></html>", [imageUrl absoluteString]];
   [webView loadHTMLString:htmString baseURL:nil];
   ```

As I think the best way is loading as HTML content. If you want you can style the html content as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Both work for me perfectly.

Are you sure you have link your webview in your xib with an IBOutlet ?

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

like this on your XIB (or Storyboard) :

[image]